# Java: error whilte sorting an array with built in function

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array with `array.sort(arr)` but there is an error which I do not understand. I tried renaming my arrays to different putting brackets in different places

```
public static int HW2K ()
    {     
      int [] arr = {50,40,60,20,10};
      int i = arr.length;
      int secondlargest = arr[i-1]; 

      Arrays.sort(arr);
      return secondlargest;  

    }
```

it should return the second largest number

Comment: What error? The result will be wrong since you choose the element before sorting the array.

Comment: the error i get in my code is with the arrays. sort it dosnt like array in array.sort:
https://imgur.com/yMxsk04

Comment: Did you import `java.util.Arrays`?

Comment: nope ;/ shouldnt that already be build in with processing though

Comment: Grammar, syntax highlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not imported `java.util.Arrays;`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class SecondLargest{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  HW2K();
}
    public static int HW2K() {
        int[] arr = { 50, 40, 60, 20, 10 };
        int i = arr.length; 
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int secondlargest = arr[i - 2];
        System.out.println(secondlargest);
        return secondlargest;

        }
}
```

Comment: thanks i was getting confused as when people where saying i need to inport  java.util.Arrays; i thought  it was a file i needed to add to my core fils, iv never had to do it before sorry

Answer (score 0):

The below should work, as mentioned in comments you should first sort your array and then choose the element you want. Also note that array index is zero based so for the 2nd biggest element you'd need `arr[i-2]`

```
public static int HW2K ()
{     
      int[] arr = {50,40,60,20,10};
      Arrays.sort(arr);
      int i = arr.length;
      int secondlargest = arr[i-2];     
      return secondlargest;  
}
```

Comment: i get erros withe the word arrays in array.sort(arr); thats why im confused with it

Comment: as others stated, add the line `import java.util.Arrays;` on top of your class. And also I highly suggest you go read some introductions to java to learn the basics

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive the second largest element in your array you must determine the element with index [length - 2] after sorting the array not before it.

> ```
> public static int HW2K()
> {
>     int [] arr = {50,40,60,20,10};
>     int i = arr.length;
>     //int secondlargest = arr[i-1];
>
>     Arrays.sort(arr);
>
>     int secondlargest = arr[i-2];
>
>     return secondlargest;
> }
> ```

Comment: how do i do htat, as when i look at the processing website there are commonds for sort so i thoight it would already be inbuilt
iv put the java files in the core files where the rest of the files are but still dosnt work

Comment: You must add "import java.util.Arrays;"